# Android and SQLite - retrieve max id from table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create method to retrieve the max id from my table but I've problem.

This is my method. It's working, but return value is 0,

```
public int getLastId() {
    openDB();
    int id = 0;
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(_id) AS _id FROM organize";
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);  
    try {
          if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MY_QUERY));
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeDB();
        }
return id;

}
```

can I fix this problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite this line

```
id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MY_QUERY));
```

to

```
id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

or better to

```
id = mCursor.getInt(0);//there's only 1 column in cursor since you only get MAX, not dataset
```

And look at LogCat, it will tell you about your problem.

Comment: I can fix this problem,Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(_id) FROM organize";
```

try only this

Comment: ya and also rewrite as emazm  said

Comment: @hohotveryspicy i tried this query but it returns maximum value 9 though i have 10 as the maximum  value can u tell why it returns 9 as max n what should i do to get the result

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
private int getMaxID(){
    int mx=-1;
    try{
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT max(ID) from tblIntents ",new String [] {});
        if (cursor != null)
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {

                mx= cursor.getInt(0);

            }
        //  cursor.close();

        return mx;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check that code inside a try block works perfectly?
 
May be code jumps into catch block and id returns 0 that you  have initialized.